# The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2005

I have a WPF application. `date` is my table and its two columns are `employeename` (`varchar(10)`)  and `date` (`datetime`)

My code is:

```
Sqlconncetion con = new Sqlconnection("my database connection ");    
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into date values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+datePicker1.Text+"')", con);    
con.Open();               
int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                
if (n > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("insert");
}
```

Actually my WPF `datepicker` formats inputs as `"dd/mm/yyyy`" and SQL Server table accept date format `mm/dd/yyyy`. How can I change my SQL Server `datetime` datatype date format? please give solution by code in c#..

My task is to display all name and birth date. My condition is basic but at time of date selection and button enter, I get exception. My code is

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my connection ");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name,date from date where date between'"+ Convert.ToDateTime( datePicker2.SelectedDate)+"' and  '"+ Convert.ToDateTime( datePicker3.SelectedDate)+"'",con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds, "entry");

da.Dispose();

dataGrid1.DataContext = ds.Tables["entry"].DefaultView;
```

plz help me solve code error and write correct code . this is a WPF application.

Comment: Don't treat dates as strings - keep them as `datetime` in the server and `DateTime` in C# (e.g. `datePicker1.SelectedDate`s value) and let ADO.Net deal with the translations required.

Answer (score 3):

Use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to pass your values to database. It gives you type safety, performance, and prevents SQL injection. Also use `using` statement to guarantee database connection will be closed:

```
var cmdText = "INSERT INTO date VALUES(@name, @date)";

using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con)) {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", textBox1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", datePicker1.SelectedDate);
     con.Open();
     int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     //...
}
```

Comment: If it's WPF DatePicker, I think it's the [`SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate.aspx) property that should be used (I made the same mistake in my comment) - it doesn't have a `Value` property.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks! For some unknown reason I thought its WinForms :)

Comment: thanx for help second task is how can retrieve data data condition base like

Comment: @user1464596 sorry, I don't understand what `retrieve data data condition base like` means. But anyway, it should be another question I think

Comment: my task is to display all name and birth date. my condition is between basic but at time of i selected date and enter in button i see exception,
my code is

Comment: @user1464596 use same approach with passing parameters to query. If you'll face some problems, create new question and someone here will help you