# The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430148/the-conversion-of-a-char-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of)

my task is to display all name and birth date. my condition is between basic but at time of i selected date and enter in button i see exception,
 my code is

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my connection ");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name,date from date where date between'"+ Convert.ToDateTime( datePicker2.SelectedDate)+"' and  '"+ Convert.ToDateTime( datePicker3.SelectedDate)+"'",con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds, "entry");

da.Dispose();

dataGrid1.DataContext = ds.Tables["entry"].DefaultView;
```

plz help me solve code error and write correct code . this is a wpf appliction

Answer (score 0):

DateTime should be formatted to be valid in sql, the format **can be** like yyyyMMdd,that is:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my connection ");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name,date from date where date between'"+ Convert.ToDateTime( datePicker2.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"' and  '"+ Convert.ToDateTime( datePicker3.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))+"'",con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds, "entry");

da.Dispose();

dataGrid1.DataContext = ds.Tables["entry"].DefaultView;
```

Comment: accounting to ur code found error No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments

Comment: That's one step in the right direction - but the **really** good solution would be to use **parametrized queries** and to forget about string-formatting of dates altogether....

Comment: I totally agree @marc_s, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your above code, the part of SQL Statement is - "select name,b_date from date where date between"

Can you please make sure the following:

1. Is "date" column there in the "date" table? should it be "b_date" instead of "date" or it is correct?
2. Can you please post what exception/error you are getting?

Thanks

Comment: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value

Comment: The code suggested by @Boomer should have worked. Can you please try the following code for the SQL Query:



`code`
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name,date from date where date between'"+ Convert.ToDateTime( datePicker2.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))+"' and  '"+ Convert.ToDateTime( datePicker3.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))+"'",con);
`code`

Comment: according ur code i find Error No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments